# R ggplot showing bent maxima

Tags: r, ggplot2

I wanted to graph a pdf that looks like this:

```r
pdf.close=function(x){
      2*(60-abs(2*x-120))/3600
}
```

This function is only defined for integers that are larger than 30 and smaller than 90 (range that makes the pdf larger than 0). For the rest of the range the function is zero.

I wrapped the above pdf so that I can apply this range specific forms.

```r
rwrap=function(f,xmin, xmax){
    ff=function(x){
    y=f(x);y[x<=xmin]=0;y[x>=xmax]=0;y
  }
}
```

Then I applied the `ggplot`.

```r
d=data.frame(x=c(1:100))
    ggplot(d, aes(x=x)) + stat_function(fun=rwrap(
            pdf.close, 29.9, 90.1), geom="line", col="blue") + 
            scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 100, by = 10))
```

The problem I have is that the drawn curve near the maxima (at x=60) is a bit bent.

ggplot result:

[image]

I'm not sure why this bend happens. Is this because my "curve" had a sharp turn?

Comment: if you use `d=data.frame(x=0:100)` it works as expected